# White Margin with body, header and html set at 0

Tags: html, css

i want to get rid of the white margin around my website . I have set on #body #header and #html margin:0; and padding:0; Can someone please help

Here is the HTML code:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header> 
<link href="CSS/stylesheet.css" rel=stylesheet>
</header>   
<body>
<div id="bannertop"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
#html{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
#header{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
#body{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
#bannertop{
   height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: cadetblue;
   margin-top:0px;

}
```

Here is a picure of the website
[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFd4K.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the # from html,body and header because # use for ID and . for class [difference between  ID & Class](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

```
html,body{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
header{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

#bannertop{
   height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: cadetblue;
   margin-top:0px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You are not referencing some of your elements correctly. The `#` selector (in front of `html`, `body` and `header` in your CSS) target elements with `id` attributes set the the value after the `#`.

Due to your HTML elements you are attempting to reference not having IDs your CSS has not targeted the elements correctly.

To fix it you must remove the `#` in front of `html` and `body`. You can also write this more concisely by using multiple selectors:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

---

FYI you have a minor mistake using `header` instead of `head`.

---

If you're currently learning HTML and CSS I recommend the following resources:

- [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/web)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn)
- [YouTube series from LearnCode.academy](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoYCgNOIyGAB_8_iq1cL8MVeun7cB6eNc)

Answer (score 0):

remove `#` before the body and html

```css
html{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
#header{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
body{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
#bannertop{
   height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: cadetblue;
   margin-top:0px;

}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header> 
<link href="CSS/stylesheet.css" rel=stylesheet>
</header>   
<body>
<div id="bannertop"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
```

it should set all the margin to 0 on every element.
you can just overide it by keeping it at the start of your css and adding diferent margins to other elements